# Database - mySQL and PHP updating conflicting information on update

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a database that holds inventory information. As staff update that information because its online its having trouble where the numbers as they are changed take the last person to updates number and use that for all the values.

Example: Joe updates cranberries are 3 left, and does not touch salad still at 3. But john updated that salad is at 0. When Joe presses update the value of salad is set back to 3 because they system thinks he is updating it too.

Any way I can fix this problem??

Comment: Can you post some code and a more in depth description? Cranberry salad sounds good though.

Comment: Can you post the sql statement that you are using, is probably not using a correct where statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both users use the same GUI where both values (cranberries and salads) may be changed at once (e.g. by pressing save button) you may:

1. Use javascript to store information in hidden field that the value has been changed by user, and then use this value when saving data in PHP to ommit values that were not changed.
2. Store original value of each property in hidden field and use it to compare it with new value from user on save to ommit saving values that were not changed.
3. Modify your GUI (e.g. adding checkbox to unlock the input where the value is to be changed
4. Use record versioning to prevent second user to change the record that has been changed since diplaying to this user. Then you can print a message like "Sorry, this record has been changed since displaying. Please refresh the page prior making changes.

Pick the one you like the best.

Comment: wow. love it. I will give it a try and see how it goes.

Comment: Enjoy :). Personally I like number 4 the best.

Comment: I would, and i agree that would be the best solution but its used so much that if that popped up every time I would be asked to remove it in no time. lol

Answer (score 1):

Sounds (somewhat) like a concurrency issue, but maybe not because we are talking about two different fields.  Take a look into locking:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-locking.html

You may wish look into how Joe gets his information, because if is still set with 3 salads and John takes them, then Joe's view doesn't know that the three salads are gone and when he clicks update (assuming all his information in his view is sent to the DB) he inadvertently puts the salads back.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem.

You can:

- [LOCK the access to this table in write mode.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/lock-tables.html)
- [Use transactions (i never did it).](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/commit.html)
- Use MySQL operations only to update quantities. (SET quantity=quantity-2, "recommended" solution)

Comment: I figured I wasnt the first to run into this. I immediately thought LOCK too but its used so often that I can no LOCK out anyone at any time. I think a combination of your "quantity=quantity-2" and hidden values to check if different will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the issue appears to be the way your SQL is possibly constructed. If a user is not changing the value of a record, there should not be a new write to that record.

By using transactions, you can check if the value has changed since the process started. This allows you to commit or rollback the transaction, depending on the outcome.

[MySQL Transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html)

For example, if User A is checking out 3 of the 5 available salads. Before User A is finished with this process, User B attempts to check out 3 of the 5 available salads as well. Using transactions, you can provide logic that will check to make sure there are enough salads left to fulfill the transaction before committing it. If the check fails, you can then rollback the transaction. This will prevent User B from checking out more salads than are available, even though the display may have indicated there were 5 available when the transaction was initiated.

Comment: Its not really how my system is built but I will give it a try,  thank you!